# CubeJS inflated count values due to LEFT JOINs on related cubes

Tags: cube.js

Consider a database schema of the following:

- An `Entity` table.
- A `SpecializedEntity` table, which has exactly 0 or 1 record for each record in `Entity`, and a nullable `LookupValueId` column.
- A `LookupValue` table, which has a record for each possible `LookupValueId`.

[image: Example database schema]

CubeJS relationships are defined as follows:

- `Entity` defines a `hasOne` relationship to `SpecializedEntity`, and `SpecializedEntity` defines a `belongsTo` relationship to `Entity`
- `SpecializedEntity` defines a `belongsTo` relationship to `LookupValue`, and `LookValue` defines a `hasMany` relationship to `SpecializedEntity`.

Finally, a `count` measure is defined on `Entity`.

When attempting to `Count` the number of entities by `LookupValueDescription`, an inflated/incorrect count (>100x higher) of `NULL` values is returned (counts for all other `LookupValueDescriptions` is correct), due to the `LEFT JOIN` generated by CUBEJS for `SpecializedEntity`.

```sql
SELECT
  TOP 10000 "lookup_value".LookupValueDescription "lookup_value__lookupValueDescription",
  count("entity".EntityId) "entity__count"
FROM
  Entity AS "entity"
  -- THIS NEXT LEFT JOIN BELOW RESULTS IN INCORRECT NULL COUNT
  LEFT JOIN SpecializedEntity AS "specialized_entity" ON "speciailized_entity".EntityId = "entity".EntityId
  LEFT JOIN LookupValue AS "lookup_value" ON "lookup_value".LookupValueId = "specialized_entity".LookupValueId
GROUP BY
  "lookup_value".LookupValueDescription
```

If the `LEFT JOIN` on `SpecializedEntity` is replaced with an `INNER JOIN`, the correct count for `NULL` values is returned.  Of course, cubejs does not support `INNER JOIN`s.

Why this `NULL` count is invalid when counts for all other values are correct?

Can the relationships between the three tables/cubes be adjusted to return a correct `NULL` count?